# Remove scroll bars from facebook login popup

Tags: facebook, authentication, popup, browser-scrollbars

I'm trying to add Facebook Login to my website using the Facebook Javascript SDK.
Everything seems to work, but the login popup opens with annoying scrollbars when asking for permissions (I'm already logged in Facebook). I tested it with Firefox 16, IE 9. Other sites that uses the Facbook login in a popup don't have the same behavior on my machine.

Perhaps they use a different approach?

Here is my code.. it's pretty simple, and you can just copy/paste in an html page to test it. Just set your APP-ID.

```
 <html>
 <body>

    <img src="images/facebooklogin.png" id="login-fb" onclick="login();" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
 window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
     FB.init({
         appId : 'APP-ID',
         status : true,
         cookie : true,
         xfbml : false
     });
 };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));


 function login()
 {
     facebookPerms = [
         'user_photos', 'email', 'offline_access', 'user_relationships', 'read_stream',
         'user_about_me', 'user_birthday', 'user_education_history', //'publish_stream',
         'user_hometown', 'user_interests', 'user_location', 'user_likes',
         'user_religion_politics', 'user_activities', 'user_work_history'
     ];

     //Get the facebook login status
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.session) {
             // logged in and connected user, someone you know
             ajaxLogin();
         } else {
             //Display the facebook login dialog
             FB.login(function(response) {
                 if (response.authResponse) {
                     // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
                     // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
                     ajaxLogin();
                 } else {
                     // user is not logged in, display the error dialog box
                     errorNotLogged();
                 }
             }, {
                 //Ask for permissions of Facebook
                 scope: facebookPerms.join(',')
             });
         }
     });
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```